# annas throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, graph, nullpointerexception, draw

I'm using the [annas](https://sites.google.com/site/annasproject/) library as a tool to visualize patterns among specific sequences of numbers in the [Collatz Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture). I'm executing this code:

```
GraphDrawer<BigInteger, DefaultArc<BigInteger>> drawer = new GraphDrawer<BigInteger, DefaultArc<BigInteger>>(graph);
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(1000, 1000, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
drawer.draw(image);
```

and it throws this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at annas.graph.drawing.GraphDrawer.draw(GraphDrawer.java:88)
    at Driver.main(Driver.java:36)
```

Safely assume `graph` is not null. What is throwing the `NullPointerException`?

---

As per Stranger's request:

```
/**
 * Draws the graph
 * 
 * @param buffImage
 *            Image to draw the graph on
 * @return graphical representation of the graph
 */
public BufferedImage draw(BufferedImage buffImage) {
    Map<N, int[]> map = this.placer.place(this.graph, sizeX, sizeY);

    ArrayList<N> nodeSet = this.graph.getNodeMap();
    ArrayList<A> arcSet;
    Graphics2D graphic = buffImage.createGraphics();
    for (N node : nodeSet) {
        arcSet = this.graph.getArc(node);
        this.nodeDrawer.drawNode(graphic, node, map.get(node)[0], map
                .get(node)[1]);
        for (A arc : arcSet) {
            this.arcDrawer.drawArc(graphic, arc, map.get(node)[0], map
                    .get(node)[1], map.get(arc.getHead())[0], map.get(arc
                    .getHead())[1]);
        }
    }
    return buffImage;
}
```

line 88 is the first line in the method (where `map` is initialized).

Comment: What is in the line 88 ?Can you add some relevant code ?

Comment: `this.placer` seems to be null. Use the other constructor, and pass a non-null placer. And submit a bug to the project, because it seems that placer should never be null, but is sometimes.